# Unexpected loading of components in Next.js 13

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css, next.js13

I am using Next.js 13 App directory together with TailwindCSS to build my website. I deployed and it is working fine. But one thing I was aware is that whenever I scroll the my footer component, the footer style and content need some time load. It is not only happening in the first time I scroll to the footer component, but whenever I scroll up and scroll to the bottom very quickly, the component load again for like 2-3 seconds and then show properly.

The 'loading' state of my footer:
[Component loading](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pGP6R.png)

After 2-3 seconds every time I scroll into the component, the style and content/text show properly:
[Component Loaded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bRefn.png)

Also, I am using the 'use client' directive to make it as a client component, because I have to use a react hook in the Footer, useContext to be exact. Therefore, I use the 'use client' directive and make it a client component.

I am not sure why this is happening because I am only creating a static page with no data fetching. All content of the page should already be generated in build time, right? Then it shouldn't be loading? I am no sure if this is a problem with TailwindCSS, Next.js 13 App dir, client component or anything else. This is really annoying as this give very bad the user experience.

Please if anyone has any idea, please help me out!

I suspected this is because of 'use client' directive and it is a behavior of the client component. I removed all client side code and removed 'use client' directive. But still it is not working. The footer compoenent still need 2-3 seconds to really have the style and content rendered.